# Oracle INSTR Function False Result

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite

I'm trying to set an HTML format if the substring is within the string using the `INSTR` function and it worked fine in this case.

```
CASE WHEN INSTR({custcol_customer_price_group},{custcol_pricing_group}) >0 
      AND {custcol_line_number} is not null 
 THEN '<font size="2" color="Green"><b></b></font>' 
 WHEN {custcol_line_number} is null 
 THEN '' 
  ELSE '<font size="2" color="Red"><b>Pricing Group Not Defined</b></font>' END
```

but now I'm trying to set the checkbox marked if the substring is not within the string and am using the function but it doesn't work

```
INSTR({custcol_customer_price_group},{custcol_pricing_group}) !=0
```

also I tried this function

```
INSTR({custcol_customer_price_group},{custcol_pricing_group}) <>0
```

Comment: Without data it is hard to tell but check that you using the parameters in the correct order. It is `{string}, {substring you want to search for}`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood what you are saying, you should check whether `INSTR` result **is equal to 0** - it means that the searched string doesn't exist in the source.

In other words: you said

> if the substring is within the string using the INSTR function and it worked fine in this case.

and used

```
INSTR({custcol_customer_price_group},{custcol_pricing_group}) > 0
```

---

Now, you're saying:

> if the substring not with the string

and used

```
INSTR({custcol_customer_price_group},{custcol_pricing_group}) != 0 
                                                              --
                                                        Wrong! Should be = 0
```

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't work also.  INSTR({custcol_customer_price_group},{custcol_pricing_group}) = 0

Comment: Could you provide sample data so that we could see what's going on? Please, post data that describe both "positive" and "negative" outcome.